# Count Points in Polygon not writing value

Tags: python

I have a "almost" running script found in StackExchange. The problem is that is does not write the result to the column 'count'.

What am I forgetting?

```
# Read the data.
polygons = gpd.GeoDataFrame.from_file('C:\code\polygon.shp')
points = gpd.GeoDataFrame.from_file('C:\code\point.shp')

# Make a copy because I'm going to drop points as I
# assign them to polys, to speed up subsequent search.
pts = points.copy()

# We're going to keep a list of how many points we find.
pts_in_polys = []

# Loop over polygons with index i.
for i, poly in polygons.iterrows():

    # Keep a list of points in this poly
    pts_in_this_poly = []

    # Now loop over all points with index j.
    for j, pt in pts.iterrows():
        if poly.geometry.contains(pt.geometry):
            # Then it's a hit! Add it to the list,
            # and drop it so we have less hunting.
            pts_in_this_poly.append(pt.geometry)
            pts = pts.drop([j])

    # We could do all sorts, like grab a property of the
    # points, but let's just append the number of them.
    pts_in_polys.append(len(pts_in_this_poly))

# Add the number of points for each poly to the dataframe.
polygons['count'] = gpd.GeoSeries(pts_in_polys)

print polygons
```

The result is

```
C:\Python27\ArcGIS10.5\python.exe "C:/Users/Bjorn ten Broeke/PycharmProjects/CountPointInPolygon/CountInPolygon_170615 - local.py"
   id  pts_p  pts_poly  count  \
0   1      0         0     12   

                                            geometry  
0  POLYGON ((8.704751258280005 50.33636457834147,...  

Process finished with exit code 0
```

So it writes out the 12, that is correct. But when I open the polgon layer, the column is empty

Comment: You need an additional instruction at bottom of code to get a copy.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need an additional instruction at bottom of code (to get a copy):

```
.
.
.

polygons.to_file('C:/code/polygon_with_count_points.shp')
```

When you open the **polygon_with_count_points** layer, the column 'count' will have desired count.

Comment: you made my day!! great works perfect!